# WMI to report Windows swapping

Tags: python, performance, memory, wmi

We are using Tim Golden's WMI Python hooks to report on the status of Windows system state to try and get similar reports to our Linux servers.

We are presently extracting the 'FreePhysicalMemory' and 'TotalVisibleMemorySize' from a 'Win32_OperatingSystem' class call.

Our problem is that memory is often reported at 100% capacity.

Is there a sensible way, using WMI/WMQ, to determine if a Windows server is swapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the various memory classes, it appears that the following will provide at least an indication of swapping:

```
SELECT PagesPersec FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory
```

According to [wmifun.net](http://library.wmifun.net/cimv2/win32_perfformatteddata_perfos_memory.html), PagesPersec is

> Pages/sec is the rate at which pages are read from or written to disk to resolve hard page faults. This counter is a primary indicator of the kinds of faults that cause system-wide delays

We're going to go for that for the time being.